# Recommended considerations to design **Data Access Layer**

Tags: asp.net, architecture, data-access-layer

What are the recommended considerations to design **Data Access Layer** for Enterprise level application. Application built in asp.net 2.0 and N-Hibernate is used in DAL, but there are many flaws in current DAL design and performance and it has been build by other team. We are planning to make new DAL design, so I am looking suggestion from experts.

Thanks

Comment: That question is way to unspecific to be answered here. You should at least have some basic ideas based on your requirements.

Comment: It would help if you can elaborate on *flaw*? This may be dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200279/best-data-access-layer-for-net

Comment: entity framework will not be choice as I have asp.net 2.0

Comment: current design is performance wise very slow.

Comment: Have you identified the performance issues to be cause by your DAL? That is are you sure it is not your database design that is the reason for the bad performance?

Comment: Yep, I think Shiv is right, usually if you are using database in your application - it is the slower part. You need to profile your app and you will get exact answer about performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net 2.0 and nHibernate scale fine to enterprise level solutions.

It must be something else that is causing the performance problems, it could be:

- Design, structure of database
- Lack of indexes
- Locking, blocking calls
- Insufficient hardware resources
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Martin Fowler (who's considered expert) wrote book titled *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture*, large portion of that book devoted to data access patterns.